# Detecting a line break & invoking a new paragraph on the output in PHP

Tags: php, html, file, file-io

So I have this snippet which gets my input from textarea named "cdet" & opens "index.php" & finds string "details" & replace it with my input-

```
if(ISSET($_REQUEST["sub"])){
    $cdet=$_REQUEST["cdet"];
    $fname = "index.php";

    $fhandle = fopen($fname,"r");
    $content = fread($fhandle,filesize($fname));
    $content = str_replace("details", $cdet, $content);
    $fhandle = fopen($fname,"w");
    fwrite($fhandle,$content); 
}

fclose($fhandle);
```

& this is the part in "index.php" where the string "details" is-

```
<p class="wNote">details</p>
```

What I want is that if a line break/new line occurs in the input, I would end the current

& invoke a new one for the new line...

e.g- if input is

Hello there..
What are you doing here?

then details should be replaced like-

```
<p class="wNote">Hello there..</p>
<p class="wNote">What are you doing here?</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can load file the easier way, with `file_get_contents()` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Then, after you get that $cdet field value use `explode()` function to split it by "\n" sign (new row). That way you'll get an array that contains rows of text.

Then iterate trough that array (with `foreach()` ) and for every row add that '`<p class="wNote">`', then row content and then '`</p>`'.

At end you can't just replace that 'details' words with your result, but you must replace whole '`<p class="wNote">details</p>`' with your output, because you can have more than one row now.

Comment: thought about explode().. but was a bit confused about it.. ok will give it a try..

Comment: ya actually it was a start.. was thinking of adding the iteration for each new line after a "<p class="wNote">" then "</p><p class="wNote">" for each & ending the iteration by a "</p>".

Comment: thanx did it :) also used get n put contents functions & omitted fopen fclose

Comment: Please consider voting up my answer if it helped you.